# Wait for Future[List[Object]] to complete asynchronously in Scala

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I have a `Future[List[Object]]` like

```
val futuresList: Future[List[Object]] = foo()
```

And I have another method which takes this `futuresList` and does some computations.

I want this future to complete execution before I can pass it to another method which returns a `Future`.

```
val futuresList: Future[List[Object]] = foo()
val anotherFuture: Future[Seq[Object]] = bar(futuresList, x, y)
```

Now I want to asynchronously wait for the futureList to complete, after which I want to pass it to `bar()`

So far I have tried this

```
futuresList.onComplete {
  case Success(data) => {  
    //call bar here, but how do I get access 'anotherFuture' ?
  }
}
```

Was hoping some guidance on how to access the response from `bar()` by making sure `futuresList` is complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val anotherFuture = futuresList.flatMap(data => bar(Future.successful(data), x, y))
```

or if you prefer the for-comprehension syntax, which is equivalent:

```
val anotherFuture = for {
  data <- futuresList
} yield {
  bar(Future.successful(data), x, y)
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't `data` be of type `List[Object]` and `bar()` requires it to be a `Future[List[Object]]` ?

Comment: My oversight.  Wrap it in `Future.successful()` then.  My answer updated.

Comment: By the way, normally if a method expect a value to be available before invocation, it take the value type directly (i.e. `Object` in your case) rather than a `Future`.  Expecting the caller to pass in completed future is error prone.  Just a casual remark, your case might be different.

Comment: Absolutely.. I was seeing some unusual sequence of execution and  I was trying to debug the same. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Technically, in this case, you can use `futuresList` iso `Future.successful(data)`

Comment: Yeah, @Viktor Klang, you're right.  What were I thinking :-)